# Open form on label double click inside flowlayout panel

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

Im trying to `Double Click` on a `Label` in a `FlowLayoutPanel`, The labels are created dynamically.
Im trying to open the form using this

```
foreach(Label label in myFlp )
{
    var Id = label.Name.ToString();
    int personID;
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id) && int.TryParse(Id, out personID))
    {
        FrmAddress frmAddress = new FrmAddress(_controller, personID);
        frmAddress.ShowDialog();
        frmAddress.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Getting this error;

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel' because 'System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
foreach(var control in myFLp.Controls)
{
    if(control is Label)
    var Id = (Label)control.Name.ToString();
    int personID;

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id) && int.TryParse(Id, out personID))
    {
        FrmAddress frmAddress = new FrmAddress(_controller, personID);
        frmAddress.ShowDialog();
        frmAddress.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I put a breakpoint at this line ` if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id) && int.TryParse(Id, out personID))`, I think this line is the problem?

Comment: That line seams correct don't think that's the problem.

Comment: When i just call the form inside `if(control is Label)`, it works without passing any variables?

Comment: Sorry, it cant find `Name` in `control`?

Comment: Look at my answer you have to cast control to label, then you find the Name property